# chamada ao modal não funciona (bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-3

Bom dia! Vou refazer a pergunta: 
monto uma tabela que recebe dados e um link para edição desses dados. Até aqui tudo certo.

O click desse link deveria abrir o modal para edição dos dados. 
Já conferi as referências ao ***Bootstrap*** e ***Jquery*** e não consigo entender o porque de ainda mostrar a mensagem de erro: ***Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function***

Abaixo os trechos do meu código:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Editar

```
<div class="modal" id="modalUsuario">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <!-- Cabeçalho do Modal -->
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3 id="myModalLabel"></h3>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Corpo do Modal -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">               
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input class = "form-control" type="text" id="txtNomeCidade" name="txtNomeCidade" placeholder = "Nome da cidade" style="width:auto;"/><br/>                 
                                </div>
                            </div><br/>
                            <div class="row">               
                                <div class="col-md-12">                 
                                    <textarea class = "form-control" style="width:auto;" class="form-control" id="informacoes" name="informacoes" rows="5" cols="33" placeholder="Informações sobre a cidade"/></textarea><br/>
                                </div>
                            </div><br/>                    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Rodapé do Modal -->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div id="mensagem_modal_edita_cidade"></div>
                        <button id="btnSalvarAlteracao" class="btn btn-success">Salvar alteração</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                        <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
                            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 

<script>
            function carregarModalEdicaoUsuario(id){
               $("#modalUsuario").modal("show"); 
            };
</script>
```

Comment: Você não precisa criar um script para abrir o modal se utilizar o HTML da forma correta.

Comment: Não precisa colocar `javascript:` dentro do `onclick`. Código dentro desse atributo já é JavaScript. Basta chamar apenas a função: `onclick="carregarModalAlterarSenha();"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não precisa chamar uma função para abrir a modal. Basta colocar na tag `<a>` os atributos:

```
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalSenha"
```

No `data-target` você coloca a id da modal. Apenas isso já abre a modal:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalSenha">Alterar senha</a>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalSenha" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Título do modal</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar mudanças</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bom dia Sam! Reformulei a pergunta. Obrigado.

Comment: Bom dia. Testando aqui seu código a modal abre sem problemas, mesmo chamando a função.

Comment: Ah sim, deve estar rolando algum conflito então... pode ser que eu esteja chamando versões diferentes do bootstrap e/ou jquery?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <a href="#" id="alterarSenha">Alterar senha</a>

    <script>
        $("#alterarSenha").click(function() {
            $("#modalSenha").modal("show"); 
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: Bom dia Alessandro. Reformulei a pergunta. Obrigado.